# Buscar y convertir datos de una consulta SQL en una cadena

Tags: php, php7, php5

Buen dia, quiero hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo dos tablas donde guardo lo siguiente tipos de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo el siguiente tipo de cadenas "***Avenida Calle*** 68 C Bis F Este 444 F Bis G 555555 Este ***Apartamento*** 5"

Quiero buscar la palabra en la cadena de texto y cambiar ese cadena por el 'abreviado', para que quede de la siguiente manera:

"***AC*** 68 C Bis F Este 444 F Bis G 555555 Este ***AP*** 5"

Agradecería vuestra ayuda y gracias por su atención

Comment: No debería bastar con un `UPDATE` donde la columna sea igual a...

Comment: Podrías ser un poco más específico ? Las cadenas están almacenadas en tu base de datos ? Cuál es el error que estás obteniendo ? Tienes algún script que puedas compartir con nosotros para entender mejor el problema ?

Comment: Colocar algo del código que has utilizado para intentar llegar a la solución, ayuda a que la comunidad tenga más elementos para poder ayudar. Revisa este enlace que te ayudará a hacer mejores preguntas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto parece un comentario, pero no lo puse en el campo correspondiente porque ya era muy largo. 
Es complicado lo que pides porque es ambiguo. El sistema tiene que saber elegir entre qué abreviar y qué no. Si el apartado fuera "TA2855" (que no hay que acortar), es un alfanumérico tan similar a "Apartamento".
Sabiendo eso, lo que se me ocurre es tengas un **arreglo de sinónimos** para reemplazar cuando detecten determinadas palabras.
Ese arreglo puede ser una tabla de la base de datos, el cual vas alimentando con tus reemplazos, o un `array` dentro de la programación, PHP en este caso.

```
<?php
// Estos dos arrays pueden ser traídos de la base de datos, o declarados en la programación.
$search = array('avenida calle', 'avenida', 'calle', 'apartado', 'apartamento', 'edificio');
$replace = array('AC', 'AV', 'C', 'ADO', 'AP', 'ED');

$string = "Avenida Calle 68 C Bis F Este 444 F Bis G 555555 Este Apartamento 5";
echo str_ireplace($search, $replace, $string); // str_ireplace, insensible a mayusc o minusc.
```

Salida

> AC 68 C Bis F Este 444 F Bis G 555555 Este AP 5